# Freeswitch ESL events filtering

Tags: python, sockets, freeswitch

FreeSWITCH (Version 1.7.0 -907-0b3f776 64bit)

I have been using Freeswitch Python ESL, but I noticed the following:
I created 2 calls using originate command:

```
originate {ignore_early_media=true,bridge_early_media=false,originate_timeout=24,call_timeout=24,execute_on_answer='sched_hangup 18',origination_uuid=5d56e91e-dfb7-4269-92cd-2967fa2d1d81,origination_caller_id_number=+18623079305}sofia/gateway/asterisk/+14084070000 handle_calls
```

Each call is created with a new ESL instance.

**Flow:**

API request -> HTTP -> Celery Task -> New ESL instance -> Send originate request.

[image]

I collected packet capture and ESL Logs and when a call is answered:
I started seeing duplicated EVENTS for CHANNEL_ANSWER over the same TCP Socket. I filtered using the SRC port, not the Freeswitch DST port. Further debugs shows that I'm receiving ALL events (The ones I subscribed) for ALL active calls.

When I subscribe to events should I receive ALL events for ALL calls over the same socket? Is this expected behavior? 
Or am I supposed to receive only events of the instance of the call used by originate command?

```
events = "BACKGROUND_JOB " \
                     "CHANNEL_OUTGOING " \
                     "CHANNEL_CREATE " \
                     "CHANNEL_ANSWER " \
                     "RECORD_START " \
                     "CHANNEL_HANGUP " \
                     "CHAN_NOT_IMPLEMENTED "


self.connection.events("plain", events)
```

Right now I'm filtering using: Channel-Call-UUID, after I receive the event. Is this the best approach?

http://pastebin.com/8jwprN7M

Comment: Freeswitch Inbound esl connection is supposed to receive events for all the calls.

Comment: Thanks I continue  filtering events by uuid and seems to behave properly.

Comment: Glad that you could filter. I've done similar task on node ESL but not by using Python lib :)